# Testing $http calls in Angular 1.1.5

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-http

I'm running into trouble trying to mock my $http calls in Angular.  When calling `$httpBackend.flush()` I'm getting the error: `Error: No pending request to flush !`

I've read up on many other posts of similar issues on here, but I still can't seem to get it to work by adding `$rootScope.$digest()` or adding `$httpBackend.expect`

I'm testing a service function:

```
getAll: function (success, error) {
            $http.get(apiRootService.getAPIRootHTTP() + "/items")
                .success(success).error(error);
},
```

Using this .spec:

```
describe ('itemAPI Module', function (){
var $httpBackend, $rootScope, itemAPI, apiRootService;
var projectID = 123;

beforeEach(module('itemAPI'));
beforeEach(module('mApp'));

/**
 * Set up variables pre-insertion
 */
beforeEach( inject( function(_$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _apiRootService_){
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    apiRootService = _apiRootService_;
}));


describe('itemAPI factory', function (){

    it('can get an instance of the metaAPI factory', inject(function(_itemAPI_){
        itemAPI = _itemAPI_;
        expect(metaAPI).toBeDefined();
    }));

    describe("get all items", function (){

        it("will return an error", function (){
            var url = apiRootService.getAPIRootHTTP() + "/items";
            $httpBackend.whenGET(url)
                .respond(400);

            var error;
            itemAPI.getAll(
                function(data, status){
                   //this is success
                },
                function(data, status){
                    error = true;
            });

            $httpBackend.expectGET(url);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(error).toBeTruthy();

        });

    });
});
});
```

Comment: Where's the `itemAPI` variable being instantied?

Comment: Removed that from the code on here because I thought it was an irrelevant test. Added now.  It's just instantiated on an it cause above what I test.

Comment: I see. You should create it inside a `beforeEach` call in order to ensure it'll be defined regardless of the order the tests run. Back to your problem, I wonder if you can create a Plunker script showing the "No pending request to flush" error? It'd be easier to debug it there.

Comment: Oh man, you're completely right.  The `beforeEach` did it.  This is what happens when I jump from unit testing to regular javascript.  Thanks a bunch.  That was a stupid mistake.

Comment: That's odd. If the `itemAPI` variable wasn't defined when the `get all items` test ran, how come you didn't get an error on `itemAPI.getAll(...)` line?

Comment: I have no idea.  But moving the injection and variable to the before each worked.  Strange, isn't it?